# JS Variable containing a string into a number

Tags: javascript

I have a function that turns an HTML element and turns it into a variable. I can not use ParseInt() or ParseFloat() because they are designed to work with strings
I do not mind using third party libraries like Jquery.

```js
var myFunction = function() {
  var myopt1 = ("#myopt1").innerHTML;
  var myopt2 = ("#myopt2").innerHTML;
  var result = myopt1 + myopt2;

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
};
```

```html
<span id="myopt1">12</span>+<span id="myotp2">12 = <span id = "result"></span>
<br/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Do Math
```

Comment: `.innerHTML` *is* a string. Use `parseInt` or `parseFloat`.

Comment: Can you clarify why you can't use parseInt?  `myopt1` is most definitely a string, right?

Comment: Also, are you using jQuery? Because you're missing the `$`. If you aren't using jQuery, you can get elements by ID using `document.getElementById('myopt1')`

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d8h9pss7/ this is the best I could do personally. There are a few problems here: Typo: "#myopt2" is meant to be "myotp2" (note otp). Also, because he is not using jquery (it wouldn't work anyway), ("#myopt1") and the other needs to be replaced by document.getElementById("myopt1").innerHTML. Then, to convert the values to integers/floats, I've just used the unary operator (+myopt1 + +myopt2).. And changed the event listener for jsfiddle. Also, there is a <span> with "12 =" which is not even closed, so it will return null and needs to be closed and separated from the " =".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have multiple problems

1)In your HTML, "myopt2" is mispelled as "myotp2"

2) Your myopt2 span's inner html is "12 = " not "12"

3) You're using jQuery style document queries incorrectly

4) You do have to convert innerHTML to a number using parseFloat() or parseInt(), to do addition instead of string concatenation

[Here is a working codepen that uses jquery](http://codepen.io/peteTalksWeb/pen/LGMLjX)

HTML:

```
<span id="myopt1">12</span>+<span id="myopt2">12</span> = <span id = "result"></span>
```

Do Math

JS:

```
var myFunction = function() {
  var myopt1 = parseFloat($("#myopt1").html());
  var myopt2 = parseFloat($("#myopt2").html());
  var result = myopt1 + myopt2;

  $('#result').html(result);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You're apparently under some misconception about something related to `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()`.  The `.innerHTML` property returns a string and `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` will take that string and turn it into number.  That's exactly what you need to do if you're trying to do number match on your two DOM elements.

In addition, the statement:

```
("#myopt1").innerHTML
```

Does not work.  In plain Javascript, you could use:

```
document.getElementById("myopt1").innerHTML
```

Working snippet:

```js
var myFunction = function() {
  var myopt1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("myopt1").innerHTML);
  var myopt2 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("myopt2").innerHTML);
  var result = myopt1 + myopt2;

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = result;
};
```

```html
<span id="myopt1">12</span>+<span id="myopt2">12</span> = <span id="result"></span>
<br/>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Do Math
```

Summary of mistakes:

1. `("#myopt1").innerHTML` does not work.  `.innerHTML` is a DOM property so you need to get a DOM element before you can use it.  You can get an HTML element for an id with `document.getElementById()`.
2. You do need to use `parseInt()` or `parseFloat()` to turn strings into numbers before doing numeric math on them.
3. `myotp2` was mispelled in your HTML.
4. Your HTML was missing a `</span>` to enclose the second number in your span tag.

Comment: @AndyKami - Did this answer your question?  If so, please indicate that to the community by clicking the green checkmark to the left of the answer.  If not, then please explain what you still need help with.